# Should I combine two tables with same fields into one?

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design

In my database I currently have two tables that are almost identical with same attributes ( **user_profile** and **contacts** )

For a quick explanation:
all user_profile have account(table user) so I did a relation 1to1 with the table user,
and the contacts of the company shouldn't have an account

I want to know is this correct design or not (user_profile and contact have same fields) :

[image: Design]

Answer (score -1):

If your contacts are never also users, it is fine to proceed this way.

You *could* setup a `Person` table and give each a type (user or contact).  It would be useful if you want to create a query to extract "all users and contacts from city X", or something like that.

If you never have any logical link between contacts and users, you can leave it like that.